# Sequelize N:M ParentModel.setChilds(ChildArray) is not a function (Magic Method?)

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

In my program, I'd  like to update many cateogories has a parent table named `Column`. Also, a category can contain of many columns.(N:M)

So I tried to update a category to the post, but it failed. Here is the code I've tried

```
let updateColumn = async function(req, res) {
  let column_id = req.body.id;
  let column_title = req.body.title;
  let column_content_text = req.body.contentText;
  let column_content_html = req.body.contentHTML;
  let column_categorys = req.body.categoris;
  let column_tags = req.body.tags;

  let column_thumbnail_url = process.env.CDN_COLUMN_ENDPOINT;
  column_thumbnail_url += column_title;
  column_thumbnail_url += '/';
  column_thumbnail_url += '0.png';

  var category_array = [];
  var tag_array = [];

  await sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {
    try {
      await Column.update({
        column_title: column_title,
        column_content_text: column_content_text,
        column_content_html: column_content_html,
        column_thumbnail_url: column_thumbnail_url,
      }, {
        where: {
          id: column_id,
        },
      }, {transaction: transaction});

      const column = await Column.findOne({
        where: {
          id: column_id,
        },
        transaction,
      });

      for(var i in column_categorys) {
        const [category, created] = await Category.findOrCreate({
          where : {
            category_name: column_categorys[i],
          },
          transaction,
        });

        category_array.push(category);
      }

      for(var j in column_tags) {
        const [tag, created] = await Tag.findOrCreate({
          where : {
            tag_name: column_tags[j],
          },
          transaction,
        });

        tag_array.push(tag);
      }

      await column.setCategorys(
        category_array,
        { transaction },
      );

      await column.setTags(
        tag_array,
        { transaction },
      );

      res.json({
        responseCode: 400,
        responseMsg: 'Success',
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.json({
        responseCode: 404,
        responseMsg: 'Fail',
      });
    }
  });
}
```

column_info.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = class Column extends Sequelize.Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    return super.init({
      column_title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(200),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      column_content_text: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(10000),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      column_content_html: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(10000),
      },
      column_thumbnail_url: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(300),
      },
    }, {
      sequelize,
      timestamps: true,
      underscored: true,
      modelName: 'Column',
      tableName: 'columns',
      paranoid: true,
      charset: 'utf8',
      collate: 'utf8_general_ci',
    });
  }

  static associate(db) {
    db.Column.belongsToMany(db.Category, {
      through: 'ColumnCategory',
      unique: false,
    });
    db.Column.belongsToMany(db.Tag, {
      through: 'ColumnTag',
      unique: false,
    });
  }
};
```

category_info.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = class Category extends Sequelize.Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    return super.init({
      category_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
    }, {
      sequelize,
      timestamps: false,
      underscored: true,
      modelName: 'Category',
      tableName: 'categorys',
      paranoid: false,
      charset: 'utf8',
      collate: 'utf8_general_ci',
    });
  }

  static associate(db) {
    db.Category.belongsToMany(db.Column, {
      through: 'ColumnCategory',
      unique: false,
    });
  }
};
```

model/index.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const User = require('./user');
const Baby = require('./baby_info');
const UserCase = require('./user_case');
const Column = require('./column_info');
const Tag = require('./tag_info');
const Category = require('./category_info');

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config')[env];
const db = {};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);

db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.User = User;
db.Baby = Baby;
db.UserCase = UserCase;
db.Column = Column;
db.Tag = Tag;
db.Category = Category;

User.init(sequelize);
Baby.init(sequelize);
UserCase.init(sequelize);
Column.init(sequelize);
Tag.init(sequelize);
Category.init(sequelize);

User.associate(db);
Baby.associate(db);
UserCase.associate(db);
Column.associate(db);
Tag.associate(db);
Category.associate(db);

module.exports = db;
```

error log

```
0|app      | 21-01-04 16:09:26: TypeError: column.setCategorys is not a function
0|app      | 21-01-04 16:09:26:     at /home/ubuntu/bebenity/routes/column/column.ctrl.js:66:20
0|app      | 21-01-04 16:09:26:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
0|app      | 21-01-04 16:09:26:     at async /home/ubuntu/bebenity/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:1090:24
0|app      | 21-01-04 16:09:26:     at async updateColumn (/home/ubuntu/bebenity/routes/column/column.ctrl.js:21:3)
```

**Could you tell me what part of this code I've used relationship queries incorrectly?**

---

#### Add 1

Actually, I've had a similar experience.
[How to add child row in related table?? (Sequelzie N:M Relationship)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65543213/how-to-add-child-row-in-related-table-sequelzie-nm-relationship)

In that example, the method **findOrCreate**'s callback value has a problem.
But, in this question, the method **findOne**'s callback value is clearly **Model** Object! I have already checked through **column instanceof Column** that the column is the Column model instance.(It is true)

But it is a little bit different between model with **Create** method and **findOne**

Create Callback

[image]

findOne Callback

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple...

Revising my `column.setCategorys` to `column.setCategories` was that...

OMG